# How To send Device Information Through An App's Internal Browser

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have a native app that has an internal web browser. 
In the web browser I will open my mobile web app that I had created myself.
What I want to do is to send the native device's information such as longtitude, latitude, battery status or device name when the user clicks a button on the interneal browser. Is there a way I can do this?

I can provide more information if needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a javascript interface. That way you can call Java methods from javascript.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html  Section "Binding JavaScript code to Android code"

To make it more clear:

1. call javascript method (javascript will call java method)
2. that java method will query android os for info you want
3. java method will return all that info back to javascript
4. javascript can now display or send those data somewhere